# How to modify linq to exclude some records?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

For below Linq, I wanted to modify it to exclude some records.
Below are existing:

```
public partial class AuditLog
{

    public AuditLog()
    {
        this.AuditLogDetail = new HashSet<AuditLogDetail>();
    }

    public string IdAuditLog { get; set; }
    public int IdUser { get; set; }
    public string Changeset { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime AuditDateTime { get; set; }
    public int AuditAction { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public int IdRecord { get; set; }
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }
    public bool IsSystem { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AuditLogDetail> AuditLogDetail { get; set; }
}


public partial class AuditLogDetail
{
    public string IdAuditLogDetail { get; set; }
    public string IdAuditLog { get; set; }
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public string OriginalValue { get; set; }
    public string NewValue { get; set; }

    public virtual AuditLog AuditLog { get; set; }
}

                     

AuditLogs = groupedLog.Where(p => p.AuditLogDetail.Any(q =>
                                                                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(q.OriginalValue) ||
                                                                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(q.NewValue)))
                            .OrderBy(p => p.AuditDateTime)
                            .Select(p => new DtoAuditLog
                            {
                                TableName = p.TableName,
                                AuditAction = p.AuditAction,
                                Details = p.AuditLogDetail.Where(q => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(q.OriginalValue) ||
                                                                      !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(q.NewValue))
                                    .Select(q => new DtoAuditDetail
                                    {
                                        ColumnName = q.ColumnName,
                                        OriginalValue = q.OriginalValue,
                                        NewValue = q.NewValue
                                    }).ToList()
                            }).ToList()
```

I wanted to exclude some columns from some Audit.Table or all columns from some Audit.Table. For that, I used below code where kept tables and columns in a list, but it could exclude when specific column was mentioned. But, didn't exclude when I mentioned no column in the list.

```
List<(string TableName, List<string> Columns)> excludedColumns = new List<(string TableName, List<string> Columns)>
{
    ("Table1", new List<string> { "Column1", "Column2" }), // Exclude Column1 and Column2 of Table1
    ("Table2", new List<string>()) // Exclude all columns of Table2
};

AuditLogs = groupedLog
    .Where(p => p.AuditLogDetail.Any(q =>
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(q.OriginalValue) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(q.NewValue)))
    .OrderBy(p => p.AuditDateTime)
    .Select(p => new DtoAuditLog
    {
        TableName = p.TableName,
        AuditAction = p.AuditAction,
        Details = p.AuditLogDetail
            .Where(q => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(q.OriginalValue) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(q.NewValue))
            .Where(q =>
            {
                var excludedColumnsForTable = excludedColumns.FirstOrDefault(ec => ec.TableName == p.TableName);
                if (excludedColumnsForTable != default((string, List<string>)))
                {
                    // Check if the current column should be excluded for this table
                    return !excludedColumnsForTable.Columns.Contains(q.ColumnName);
                }
                return true; // Include the column if it's not specified in the exclusion list
            })
            .Select(q => new DtoAuditDetail
            {
                ColumnName = q.ColumnName,
                OriginalValue = q.OriginalValue,
                NewValue = q.NewValue
            }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: An empty column name list in the tuple would indicate exclude no columns, since membership in the list is required to exclude a particular `ColumnName`. If you want to treat an empty list to mean exclude all columns, change your `return` in the `Where` lambda to say that: `excludedColumnsForTable.Columns.Count > 0 && `...